# How to increase the width of the text fields in docusign

Tags: docusign

I'm creating custom anchor tabs dynamically, I have the below properties for a anchor tab.

```
    DocusignAPI_Util.Tab anchorTab = new DocusignAPI_Util.Tab();
    anchorTab.AnchorTabString = '_'+setting.AnchorTabString__c+ nameNum;
    anchorTab.tabType = 'Custom';
    anchorTab.tabLabel = setting.AnchorTabString__c+ nameNum;
    anchorTab.customTabType = setting.customTabType__c;
    anchorTab.CustomTabHeight = Integer.valueOf(setting.CustomTabHeight__c) ;
    anchorTab.CustomTabWidth = Integer.valueOf(setting.CustomTabWidth__c);
    anchorTab.CustomTabRequired = setting.CustomTabRequired__c;
    anchorTab.ignoreIfNotPresent = true; 
    anchorTab.valueObj = setting.value__c != null ? setting.Value__c : fieldWhiteSpaceLength;
    anchorTab.CustomTabLocked = false;
    anchorTab.CustomTabDisableAutoSize = true;
    return anchorTab;
```

According to the documentation ([Documentation: Tab](https://www.docusign.com.au/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/Tab.htm?Highlight=Formula)) "CustomTabWidth" should work if I say;

anchorTab.CustomTabWidth = 100;

This doesn't work as expected, any reason? am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation;

> It is the responsibility of the document author to provide sufficient
>   whitespace to contain the potential width of the ultimate tab value.

[Documentation link](https://www.docusign.com.au/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Anchoring%20Tabs.htm)

Your code has to be changed as below.

```
.....

anchorTab.valueObj = setting.value__c != null ? setting.Value__c : '         ';

.....
```